How to move a connected audio clip into the primary timeline?
The following works:

add audio clips from the browser to the primary timeline

The following works:

drag and edit audio clips already in the primary timeline

However, I'm unable to:

move audio clips that are connected to the primary timeline, into the primary timeline

I've tried various things like, creating a compound clip from the connected audio clip,then dragging that into the primary timeline, then breaking that apart, but when I break it apart, the audio straight away leaves the primary timeline (leaving a grey 'gap' generator in its place).
I want my video clips to be attached to my audio clips. I could create a secondary timeline from my audio clips, but I don't see a way to attach video clips to the secondary audio timeline? So, when I edit the audio, the video clips all becom out of sync, and have to move each of the video clips, one by one...
The worst case is to drag each of the audio clips, one by one, from the browser, into the primary story line, and re-edit them. But this will take forreevvver. (unless there's a quick way to do this, keeping the original edits, timings, relative positions, etc?)
Thoughts?
